# PHP back to search result after click any button or link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `php` page in this page i show data from `mysql` database in a table also in the same page i have an `HTML` form to do some search and the result of this search also appear in the same page.

Each row of this table have an icon `delete` when i click this icon i delete the information of this row from `mysql` database.

This my delete code

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $deleteid=secure($_GET['delete'],"num");
    $checkQuery=mysqli_query($conn,"select column from table where column='$deleteid' limit 1")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkQuery)==1){
        dbRowDelete("table","WHERE column='$deleteid'");
        header("location:gm-tasks.php?msg=8");
    }else{
        header("location:gm-tasks.php");
    }
}
```

An example of my show data and search code:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['clear']) ){
//show all data
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//Show search results
}
```

My question is how can after i delete a row to back to the search result.

I don't want after delete to show all data i want only to show the result of the search without the row i was delete.

I have tried this `$_SERVER['http_referrer'];` but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: As for your question, we don't know how your search results are displayed in the first place, so we can't say how to go back to them. Presumably you need to pass on, or store some parameters pertaining to the most recent search.

Comment: It's bad practice to use `GET` for modifying data. The `GET` parameter should *only* be used for retrieving data.

Comment: @ADyson — Possibly vulnerable. We can't see what the `secure` function does. (I'm betting it isn't something I'd trust though).

Comment: @Quentin agreed, but the safest thing is to use parameterisation nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you all for you idea i will work on it and i will change my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have POST and GET backwards.

- GET should be safe. You should not use GET to delete things. POST can be unsafe. You should use POST to delete things (that or DELETE, which isn't practical with a regular form submission). (This is according to the HTTP specification).
- GET is designed to GET information. You should use GET when you are searching to show data.
- GET stores data in the URL, so you can link to it. POST does not. You need to link to the search results to go back to them.

Comment: ok you suggest is to change my search form to get and use post to delete any data

Comment: if i change my form to get how can i back to my search results?

Comment: Then the search results will have their own URL and you can link to it. Referrer will possibly do the job. Or you can encode the URL of the current page in the POST data with a hidden input.

Comment: can you please give me an example to understand more you idea ?!